# ('div').animate({top:'+=10px'},500), confused by code inbetween { }

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

First of all, what does the { } do, why is it needed and what exactly is it called when it does this? Why can't I just use "top:+=10px" for my css, why do I need { }.

second, why do I need only one comma on each side of +=10px, what do the commas do and why can't I use 'top:+=10px instead of top:'+=10px'?

I don't know what this is called so I don't know how to properly look up the terminology of what I am asking.

```
('div').animate({top:'+=10px'},500);
```

Comment: `{}` is an object and the comma separates function parameters. I suggest you read a beginner tutorial or two. These are very basic concepts.

Comment: The first argument of the animate method is an object of CSS properties and values.

Comment: So you are declaring an object without a name basically? Why do you need the commas, why can't I just use +=10px without it? I know the colon is to separate the parameter and value. I have done a beginner course in CSS but they never put in variables in this format before in javascript

Comment: Ok, there seems to be a bit of a language issue here. This is a comma: `,` When you say comma you're talking about (single) quotes (`'`). Secondly, you're *not* passing CSS to the method, so thinking about it as CSS syntax isn't helpful here. You might want to read [the method's documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

The `{ }` denotes an Object in JavaScript. By setting `{top: '+=10px'}, 500` you are setting a property `top` and telling jQuery you want it to animate X amount from the `top` over the course of `500` milliseconds.

You can find documentation on this [here](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

You need to remember that you are writing jQuery, which is JavaScript, and therefore the syntax will be different compared with the CSS you are used to writing.